# Gradient of sum of products of matrix traces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, trace

For a matrix $X \in \Re_{n\times d}$ find the gradient of

$\sum_{i,j}[\langle X_{i.},X_{j.} \rangle\operatorname{tr}(X^TA_{ij}X)]$ w.r.t $X$, 
where $A_{ij}=(e_i-e_j)(e_i-e_j)^T$ using the basis vectors while $X_{i.}$ denotes the $i$'th row. Do note that, $\langle X_{i.},X_{j.} \rangle$ can be written as $\langle X_{i.},X_{j.} \rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(X^Te_ie_j^TX)$ making the original question a sum of products of trace functions.

Hint: The gradient of $\operatorname{tr}(X^TMX)$ w.r.t $X$ for any real matrix $M$ is given by $MX+M^TX$.

Comment: How can the derivative of a real number be a sum of vectors?

Comment: @xavierm02 I think that as in the case of derivative of scalar w.r.t. vector: $\frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial X}$ is such a matrix $Y$ that $f(X+\Delta X)-f( X) = \langle Y,\Delta X \rangle + o(\Delta X)$, where $\langle,\rangle$ is the Euclidean scalar product. Note that $\langle Y,X \rangle = \mathrm{tr} \; (Y^T X)$

Comment: @xavierm02  Refer to the table with gradients and derivatives of functions involving trace (scalar), and other matrix and vector 'valued' functions  with 'domains' being scalar, vector or matrix domains at: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dattorro/matrixcalc.pdf Nimza..You are right.

Comment: I don't get how the derivative of $\operatorname{tr}(X^TMX)$ (scalar) can be $MX+M^TX$ (vector)...

Comment: @xavierm02 Simple: $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_{k}}x^TAx=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ia_{ik} + a_{k.}^Tx=Ax+A^Tx$. Now in the case of trace: $\frac{\partial tr(AB) }{\partial a_{ij}}=b_{ij}$. Hence, $\nabla_A trAB = B^T$ and so on and so forth, where you see in the case of the trace, which is a scalar valued function, the gradient is  vector/matrix valued.

Comment: $\langle X_{i.},X_{j.} \rangle = \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^Te_ie_j^TX).$ Given the structure of $A_{ij}$ that seems rather important...

Comment: Yeah, the $i,j$'s are iterating on terms based on $e_i,e_j$ in both the trace functions and it seems to be a sum of product of trace functions-as a generic format here.

Comment: We also have a product of two functions of the matrix $X$ and I am wondering, if a simple chain rule can be applied. That said, we compute the derivatives under the $i,j$ subscripts and add them up? It sounds a bit funny-;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's normalize the notation by rewriting the inner product.
$$\langle X_{i.},X_{j.} \rangle = \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^Te_ie_j^TX) = 
\tfrac{1}{2}\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^T(e_ie_j^T+e_je_i^T)X)$$
Let $B_{ij}\triangleq e_ie_j^T+e_je_i^T$. The expression, which we will call $f(X)$, simplifies to
$$
f(X)=\tfrac{1}{2}\sum_{ij} \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TB_{ij}X)\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TA_{ij}X)
$$
The gradient follows from a combination of the standard product rule and the fact that $\nabla X\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TPX)=2PX$ when $P$ is a symmetric constant. (This is why we took the extra symmetrizing step above.) The gradient is
$$
\nabla_Xf(X)=\sum_{ij} \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TB_{ij}X)A_{ij}X + \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TA_{ij}X)B_{ij}X = (Q + R) X,
$$
where $Q$ and $R$ are defined as follows:
$$
Q \triangleq \sum_{ij} \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TB_{ij}X)A_{ij}, \quad
R \triangleq \sum_{ij} \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TA_{ij}X)B_{ij}.
$$
Let's find some clean expressions for $Q$ and $R$. For $Q$, we have
$$
\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TB_{ij}X) 
= \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^T(e_ie_j^T+e_je_i^T)X)
= 2e_i^TXX^Te_j = 2Z_{ij}
$$
where $Z\triangleq XX^T$. Continuing:
$$
Q = \sum_{ij} 2Z_{ij}A_{ij} = \sum_{ij} 2Z_{ij}(e_i-e_j)(e_i-e_j)^T
= \sum_{ij} 2Z_{ij} ( e_ie_i^T + e_je_j^T - e_ie_j^T - e_je_i^T )
$$
For each $(i,j)$, this expression adds $Z_{ij}$ to elements $Q_{ii}$ and $Q_{jj}$, and subtracts $Z_{ij}$ from $Q_{ij}$ and $Q_{ji}$. (When $i=j$, these steps cancel.) The total is then multiplied by two. This will do that:
$$
Q = 2(\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(Z\textbf{1})+\mathop{\textrm{diag}}((\textbf{1}^TZ)^T)-Z-Z^T)=4\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(Z\textbf{1})-4Z
$$
The $\mathop{\textrm{diag}}$ operator constructs a diagonal matrix from a column vector. You can verify this result by substituting $Z\rightarrow Z_{ij}e_ie_j^T$ into the first form for $Q$ above and simplifying; the result should equal the $(i,j)$ summand.

Now consider the second term in the summation:
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TA_{ij}X) &= \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^T(e_i-e_j)(e_i-e_j)^TX) \\& = (e_i-e_j)^TXX^T(e_i-e_j) = Z_{ii}+Z_{jj}-Z_{ij}-Z_{ji}\end{aligned}$$
$$
R=\sum_{ij} \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X^TA_{ij}X)B_{ij} = \sum_{ij} (Z_{ii}+Z_{jj}-Z_{ij}-Z_{ji})(e_ie_j^T+e_ie_j^T)
$$
This summation copies each quantity $Z_{ii}+Z_{jj}-Z_{ij}-Z_{ji}$ to the $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ positions. Thus $R$ is
$$R=2(\mathop{\textrm{diag}^*}(Z)\textbf{1}^T+\textbf{1}\mathop{\textrm{diag}^*}(Z)^T-Z-Z^T)=2\mathop{\textrm{diag}^*}(Z)\textbf{1}^T+2\textbf{1}\mathop{\textrm{diag}^*}(Z)^T-4Z.$$
The $\mathop{\textrm{diag}^*}$ operator extracts the diagonal elements of a matrix into a column vector.

The final result, therefore, is
$$
\boxed{
\begin{aligned}
\nabla_X f(X) &= 
(4\cdot\mathop{\textrm{diag}}(XX^T\textbf{1})
+2\cdot\mathop{\textrm{diag}^*}(XX^T)\textbf{1}^T \\ &\quad
+2\cdot\textbf{1}\mathop{\textrm{diag}^*}(XX^T)^T
-8\cdot XX^T)X.
\end{aligned}}
$$

Comment: Given $X$ is of dimension $n \times 2$ we get that $XX^T\mathbb{1}$ is $n \times 1$ dimensions. What does $diag(XX^T\mathbb{1})$ mean as we are looking for a diagonal of a column vector?

Comment: Two different operators here. $\mathop{\textrm{diag}}$ creates a diagonal matrix from a vector. Its adjoint $\mathop{\textrm{diag}^*}$ extracts the diagonal from a matrix, returning a vector

Comment: Got it. So, you meant diag takes as input a vector! Thanks for the answer with the clear explanation of the manipulations.

Comment: Right. It is confusing because MATLAB uses the same command for both directions. So in formulae I try to be consistent and use the adjoint notation to differentiate between the two operations.

Comment: also a quick question, is there some software that would allow a symbolic entry of the gradient equation in this answer, so that I can solve the system for $X$ easily? or do you see this as more complicated! I hope if done on paper, the system dosn't look like a Sylvester equation, or some complicated format ;)

Comment: I doubt it. In fact I doubt a symbolic solve is possible. You will need to do a numeric minimization, assuming that is what you are seeking.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8436/discussion-between-michael-grant-and-halms)

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the guess. That's right am looking for a numeric minimization.

Answer (score 1):

Given the standard basis vectors $(e_k)$ and matrices $(E_{ij}=e_ie_j^T)$ construct an all-ones vector and matrix.
$$f = \sum_k e_k, \quad F = \sum_{ij} E_{ij}\quad\implies F=ff^T$$
Define some auxiliary variables
$$\eqalign{
M &= XX^T = M^T &\implies dM = 2\,{\rm Sym}(dX\,X^T) \\
\mu_{ij} &= (E_{ij}:M) = \mu_{ji}
  &\implies M=\sum_{ij} \mu_{ij}E_{ij} \\
B &= I\odot M &\implies dB = I\odot dM \\
b &= {\rm diag}(M) = Bf &\implies bf^T = Bff^T = BF \\
\beta_{k} &= b:e_k \;\doteq \mu_{kk} 
  &\implies b=\sum_{k} \beta_ke_k \\
A_{ij} &= E_{ii} + E_{jj} - E_{ji} - E_{ij} \\
\lambda_{ij} &= (A_{ij}:M) \\
 &= \mu_{ii} + \mu_{jj} - \mu_{ji} - \mu_{ij}  \\
 &= \beta_{i}{\tt1}_j + {\tt1}_i\beta_{j} - 2\mu_{ij}  \\
 &= (E_{ij}:L) 
  &\implies L=\sum_{ij} \lambda_{ij}E_{ij} \\
L &= bf^T + fb^T - 2M \\
}$$
where

$\quad{\rm Sym}$ denotes the symmetrization function  $\;{\rm Sym}(X)=\tfrac{1}{2}(X+X^T)$

 $\quad(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product

 $\quad(\;:\;)$ denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. 
$\;M\!:\!L={\rm Tr}(M^TL)=\sum\mu_{ij}\lambda_{ij}$

The objective function is now easy to handle.
$$\eqalign{
\phi
 &= \sum_{ij}\mu_{ij}\lambda_{ij} \;= M:L \\
 &= M:(bf^T + fb^T - 2M) \\
 &= 2M:(bf^T - M) \\
 &= 2M:(BF - M) \\
d\phi
 &= 2\,dM:(BF - M) + 2M:(dB\,F - dM) \\
 &= 2(BF - M):dM + 2MF:(I\odot dM)  - 2M:dM \\
 &= \big(2BF - 2M + 2I\odot MF - 2M\big):dM \\
 &= 2\,{\rm Sym}\big(2BF + 2I\odot MF - 4M\big)X:dX \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X} &= \big(2BF + 2FB + 4I\odot MF - 8M\big)X \\
}$$